# Facebook Feed API is not returning the comment data in its response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using this Facebook API to get feeds including the comments data. It used to work but all of sudden it started to return no comment data. It started to happen around Jun 26, 2023. It means this API returns the feed but no comment.

We have been following this API documentation to fetch the feed along with all its comments and replies
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed

We do not see any recent changes on the Facebook API documentation but all of a sudden this API not working as expected.

The API we have been using:

https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/user_id?fields=id,name,link,feed.fields(id,message_tags,to,from,created_time,privacy,place,message,story,attachments,properties,comments.fields(id,from,message,attachment,created_time,message_tags).order(reverse_chronological).limit(5)).since(1680681867).until(1688457867).limit(100)&access_token=some_token

Please see the attached screenshot, the JSON response has the feeds but no comments. For testing I have created new feeds and added comments on that feed for that particular facebook user but still no luck.
I have made sure the since and until are passed correctly. I used the most recent date for until.

I have tried using the latest version but no luck. I have granted all the permission but still no luck.  Looks like comments edge is not working as expected.
Please see the screenshot of Graph API Explorer,

Please also note that the same API works perfectly fine if I pass pageid. In such case, it returns the feeds along with its comments in the response payload.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]